# How to pass a list to a thread without copying it, while destroying the original

Tags: c++, multithreading, rvalue

This code creates and executes a thread that needs to get the contents of `std::list<int> data` without the contents of this list being copied and changing it's address into memory.  Pointers into the list have to stay valid for other code.

After the thread is created, the original list `data` is destroyed in the main thread, so I cannot use it's address in this case.

How can I accomplish this?  I've tried using rvalue references, though I worry I might have a dangling pointer if I attempt it in that fashion.  Here is what I have:

```
void func(std::list<int> && data){  // <-- what should go here as an argument?
   std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
   // do stuff with data
}

int main(){
    {
        std::list<int> data;
        data.push_back(1);
        std::thread(func, std::move(data)).detach();
    } 
    // data destroyed
}
```

Comment: I would be much surprised if this ever caused a memory corruption. Still, why DO you accept by reference ? There's no other reason than to confuse people (including yourself). It would only have been a memory corruption if you had passed the list to the thread from main() using a std:: reference_wrapper

Comment: @arne - I have the keep the contents of the list at the same address (other code keeps pointers to them that have to stay valid), so I have to avoid copying.  Passing by rvalue, I am hoping, explicitly avoids copying, whereas passing by value is allowed to copy.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean there. There is never a copy of the vector's contents being made here, just an exchange of raw pointers from std::list. The original list from main() however is empty now, so why would you keep a reference to it ? In the sample above func() is passed a reference from the contents of std::thread, not of a variable inside main(). As I said, you need std:: reference_wrapper to pass a true reference to the thread.

Comment: @ArneJ - Sorry for the confusion, I've rewrote the question to broaden and hopefully clarify the problem

Comment: There will be no dangling reference and the data dlements themselves are not moved (see reference of std::list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor of `thread` calls

```
std::invoke(decay_copy(std::forward<Function>(f)), 
            decay_copy(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
```

where `decay_copy` is defined as follows:

```
template <class T>
std::decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&& v) { return std::forward<T>(v); }
```

You are passing `move(data)`. Because `decay_copy` uses reference forwarding, so it returns `T&&`, because `decay_t` discards constness and referenceness the new list object is created by using move constructor. So `data` list from `main` was moved into thread constructor (`thread` stores its params on tuple - you don't need to care about the lifetime of moved data list object. Now, the question is how you want to pass/access moved `data` list in `func`. By copy/move or reference, details below).

Now `invoke` is called:

```
invoke (func, temporary list object returned by decay_copy)
```

and here there are two cases to be considered:

[1] `func` has signature `func(list<int>&&)`, in this case you are just accessing moved list object by reference - no copy, nor move operations are called.

[2] `func` has signature `func(list<int>)`, in this case move constructor will be called on list. If list didn't have move supports, copy operation would be called here.

So use `list<int>&&`, you will save one move operation.